# How can i retrieve default post per page value? from settings->reading. And total number of posts?

Tags: wp-query, pagination

I want to retrieve the default value of Post per page (the value that is set in settings->reading.

I've looked around and so far I've only found ways to query it. problem is i dont want to change what was set i just want to retrieve it for pagination purposes. i thought of using `$something->post_count.`(i might be wrong but as i understand it returns the amount of posts displayed currently) but this could be wrong in some cases.

Also how can i get the total number of posts ?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

It's saved in an option:

```
$default_posts_per_page = get_option( 'posts_per_page' );
```

Reference: [get_option Parameters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_option#Parameters)

You can see the keys and values of all available options by manually entering the admin url:

> /wp-admin/options.php

### Edit

Total number of posts:

```
global $wp_query;
$total_posts = $wp_query->post_count;
```

Comment: thank you very much milo i was looking for it entirely in the wrong place.. How do i get the total number of posts though ? Post count is not just for current page ?

Comment: @YanivKossas - sorry, missed that part of the question, Chip has edited the answer in there.

Comment: post_count however returns the number of posts currently displayed that mean if you have posts_per_page set to 3 and you have 40 post it will return - 3 however if you have lets say 5 posts and you are on page 2 it will return 2 if that makes sense - it doesn't return the total number of posts

Comment: if you want total number of posts for a query use `$wp_query->found_posts`. You can determine the remainder on the last page with found_posts and `$wp_query->max_num_pages`

Comment: these possibilities are from "2013" ... Apparently, they are out of date ...
Any updates after several wordpress updates?

Comment: @PauloBoaventura 10 years later and still no better answers :)